# Selenium1 - Commands are failing in Mac - Safari5 on HTTPS page 

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I m using selenium1 to automate my web application. Recently i started running test cases in Mac machine and found few issues. Selenium methods are not working correctly in Mac machine Safari browser(Ver. 5) on https pages. Any workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: yes, type is failing in HTTPS scenario.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  How are you running your script?  What exactly happens?  Which Selenium command fails?  Does the same test work with FireFox or Chrome?

Comment: yes, the same tests are running fine with firefox, IE8 & chrome. This issue is already reported in google groups and nobody answered this question yet[ http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/a6ea375c997f9cd3]. On https page, test cases are failing with element not found error message.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://saucelabs.com/docs/https) implies there is not good support for your scenario in Safari:

> Sauce OnDemand is configured to take full advantage of what Selenium
>   can do, though some limitations do remain, such as poor Safari support
>   and trouble navigating between HTTP and HTTPS domains.

Are you using *safari or *safariproxy?  Is the SSL certificate self-signed or valid?  You could try switching those.